# How can I add command line arguments when compiling and running a C program in Xcode?

Tags: c

When I work on C currently, I use Xcode and just press *Build & Run* in the Debugger Console which shows all the program's output.

[image: Example]

I want to test iterating through command line arguments now. I tried to fake it with...

```
int main() {    
    char *argv[] = {"echo","-n","hello world!"};
    int argc = 3;
}
```

But trying to iterate through `argv` kept giving me an error...

> error: lvalue required as increment operand

When I tried to `++argv`.

So, I'm wondering, how can I give some command line arguments to my program when I run it this way, or do I need to compile and then run it with Terminal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Project -> Edit Active Executable` and add your arguments on the `Arguments` tab.